# Set the background image as device width and device height in xml file

Tags: android, react-native

I want to display the bg image as the splash screen. So how can I set the image to device screen width and device screen height. Can I do it from the xml file below (this xml file is inside drawable folder) . I tried to put fill_parent or match_parent in the width but it gives error. Is there any way to do it?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <item
        android:drawable="@color/white"/>

    <item
      android:drawable="@mipmap/bg"
      android:gravity="center"
      android:width="300dp"
      android:height="600dp"/>

</layer-list>
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace `android:drawable="@color/white` with background drawable.

```
<!-- in your_splash_screen.xml -->
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
        <layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
            <item android:drawable="@drawable/your_background" />
        </layer-list>

<!--in values.xml -->
    <style name="AppTheme.SplashScreen" parent="AppTheme">
        <item name="android:windowFullscreen">true</item>
        <item name="android:windowTranslucentStatus">true</item>
        <item name="android:windowBackground">@drawable/your_splash_screen</item>
    </style>

<!--in AndroidManifest.xml -->
        <activity
            android:name=".SplashActivity"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.SplashScreen">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
```

Comment: @AmritaStha I've updated my answer. See if it works.

Answer (score 0):

Set the image to the `ImageView` in the splash screen and set the `scaleType` attribute of the `ImageView` as `"fixXY"`.